# How do I increase the page size in draw.io?

Tags: app.diagrams.net

How do I increase the size of the page in draw.io?

I'm making a flowcart and need the page to increase vertically.

Answer (score 11):

Open the File->Page Setup dialog:

[image: draw.io file menu]

And enter the paper size you require:

[image: draw.io page setup dialog]

Comment: File -> Page Setup (3rd from the bottom) -> change size

Answer (score 4):

Just because this question comes up when you search "infinite canvas draw.io", here's how to make an actual infinite canvas:

On the right-side tray, select the "Diagram" tab and uncheck "Page View":

[image]

Comment: The page background view is nothing to do with what part of the canvas is usable. The canvas is "infinite" all the time, just if you drop a shape where there's not already a page drawn, it will draw it there.

Comment: This is the real right answer. Thank you kind internet stranger 