# Adjust canvas size to image for draw.io

Tags: app.diagrams.net

Inkscape has a wonderful option to resize the canvas to fit the image.

Does this option exist in draw.io ?

I am drawing an image in draw.io which takes 10% more than the actual canvas size. However, due to this draw.io is adding 100% more space horizontally : 90% of the new horizontal space is wasted.

Comment: See http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/69098/how-do-i-increase-the-page-size-in-draw-io for the answer

Comment: @EmielSteerneman 's link doesn't appear to be any different to the answer here. It also suggests the manual resize operation, although the focus of the question is on increasing the canvas rather than decreasing as asked here.

Answer (score 7):

You can resize the canvas from the toolbar on the right. Deselect any items that you may be manipulating and then the "Diagram" toolbar should appear. Look at the section called "Paper Size", you can adjust the canvas size there.

[image: Paper Size Section]

Comment: Doesn't quite answer the question - this is a manual resize operation (Inkscape's feature calculates it based on the bounding box of all the elements).